# Change location of storing mysql database

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, database, database-administration

Im running a linux server and I wondering if and how could I change the contents of Mysql server to be saved on an external hardrive instead of the place where it is being stored now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `datadir` option in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir

http://kaliphonia.com/content/linux/how-to-move-mysql-datadir-to-another-drive